# Number sequence program speed

Tags: c++, sequence

I have this number sequence - xm = y.xm-1 + z (mod 20 000).

These are the restrictions:
1 ≤ x < 20 000, 
0 ≤ y, z ≤ 9,
1 ≤ N ≤ 2 000 000 00
And here is my [code][1].

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

double k =0;
int x,y,z;
unsigned long long n;

int solve()
{
    int result = 0;
    int prevX = x;
    for(unsigned long long i =1; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(result<20000)
        {
            result = y * prevX+z;
            prevX = result;

        }
        else
        {
             result = y * prevX+z;
             result = result % 20000;
             prevX = result;

        }

    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
int tests =0;
cin >> tests;
cin.ignore();
 while(tests--)
    {
    scanf("%d %d %d %Ld", &x, &y, &z, &n);
    int result = solve();
    cout << result;
    }

}
```

Example input: 
1 
2 3 4 10

Example output:
18730

Details: 
1 on the first row is the number of input test.

2 3 4 10 - x,y,z, N;
The judging system that I'm using is giving me a time limit error. So my program is slow.

Is there any way to predict this number sequence, elimanating most of the cycles?

Comment: Please paste code directly into the question.

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, given an initial value of `x`, `y`, and `z`, you have to compute the Nth term of the sequence defined by `x[m] = y * x[m - 1] + z mod 20000`. This can be computed quickly using matrix exponentiation. See https://web.archive.org/web/20160302230252/http://fusharblog.com/solving-linear-recurrence-for-programming-contest/. The code there is bad but the explanation of the algorithm is useful.

Comment: @BessieTheCow If I understood the given link, my sequence is not linear, because i have multiplication.

Comment: You're multiplying by a constant so its perfectly linear. `y` may be different in each test case but for each sequence it's the same no matter which term you're on so it's a constant. You're just going to have to generate the transform matrix at runtime based on the values of `y` and `z`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is linear, because you have a loop from 0 to N. You can do logarithmic instead.

You can get to the equation empirically, with a simple experiment, just plug in a number, like `m = 4`. Let's ignore the modulo part for the moment because we can just do this on the final number (see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Integers_modulo_n).

```
x[4] = y * x[3] + z
     = y * (y * x[2] + z) + z
     = y^2 * x[2] + y * z + z
     = y^2 * (y * x[1] + z) + y * z + z
     = y^3 * x[1] + y^2 * z + y * z + z
```

So you can easily get the rule, if you don't, start with `m = 5`. It is:

```
x[m] = y^(m-1) * x[1] + y^(m-2) * z + ... + y^0 * z
     = y^(m-1) * x[1] + z * (y^(m-2) + ... + y^0)
```

Observe, that this is a [geometric series](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html), i.e.

```
x[m] = y^(m-1) * x[1] + z * (y^(m-1) - 1) / (y - 1) mod 20000
```

So what remains is to calculate `y^(m-1)`, which you can do in `log m` easily.

In all steps be aware of the modulo rules! I.e., if you calculate `y * y mod 20000`, calculate `(y mod 20000) * (y mod 20000) mod 20000` instead.

---

## Example

Let's take `z = 10`, `y = 11`, `x[1] = 3`, then you have

```
    x[2] = 11 * 3 + 10 mod 20000 = 43
    x[3] = 11 * 43 + 10 mod 20000 = 483
    x[4] = 11 * 1850 + 10 mod 20000 = 5323
    x[5] = 11 * 460 + 10 mod 20000 = 58563 mod 20000 = 18563
```

Or you can get it directly:

```
    x[5] = 11^4 * 3 + 10 * (11^4 - 1) / (11 - 1) mod 20000
         = 14641 * 3 + 10 * (14641 - 1) / 10 mod 20000
         = 43923 + 14640 mod 20000
         = 644204 mod 20000
         = 18563
```

Remember that if `y == 19284`, you calculate the fourth power as `(y^2 mod 20000)^2 mod 20000 = 12656^2 mod 20000 = 14336` to ensure that you don't get overflows.

Comment: `x[m] = y^(m-1) * x[1] + z * (y^(m-1) - 1) / (y - 1) mod 20000` 

Can you show me an example with some numbers? Like if N is 2 or 3, so x[m] should be 34. x[1] = 2.3+4 = 10; x[2] = 10.3+4 = 34; 
With the equation above i get different result, im doing wrong at some operation.

Comment: Check the example. Does your example start with  `x[0]` or `x[1]`? Maybe you have to adapt for `x[0].`

Comment: You are great! Works like charm, actually the first time I did the calculations right, but few hours after i messed up.